# Android: How to integrate a decoder to multimedia framework

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-framework, stagefright

Recently i have ported a video decoder to android successfully. Also dumped the output on a surfaceview and checked the output using native API's. Now the next task is to implement play, pause, streaming etc. i.e. the other features of the media player. Doing this will be a rework as all these functionalities are already defined in the android multimedia framework. I heard that we can make our decoder as a plug-in and integrate it into Android's multimedia framework. Although i googled regarding the same, i could hardly find any info regarding the same. So i kindly request any of the readers to suggest some relavent links or solution for the above problem. Thanks in advance, waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Android SF framework, the codecs are registered through `media_codecs.xml`.  In standard android distribution, an example `media_codecs.xml` can be found [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/development/tools/emulator/system/camera/media_codecs.xml). All audio-visual components are registered as `OMX` components.

**1. Codec Registration**

To register your video decoder, you would have to add a new entry under `<Decoders>` list. To ensure that your codec is always picked up, please ensure that your codec is listed as the first entry for the specific `MIME` type. An example entry for a H.264 decoder could be as below.

```
<Decoders>
    <MediaCodec name="OMX.ABC.XYZ.H264.DECODER" type="video/avc" >
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-input-ports" />
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-output-ports" />
    </MediaCodec>
    <MediaCodec name="OMX.google.h264.decoder" type="video/avc" />
```

Where,

a.`OMX.ABC.XYZ.H264.Decoder` is the name of your component

b. `video/avc` is the `MIME` type of your component. In this example, it denotes a **AVC** / **H.264** video decoder.

c.The next 2 statements denote the `quirks` or **special requirements** of your components. In the given example, `requires-allocate-on-input-ports` indicates to the `Stagefright` framework that the component prefers to allocate the buffers on all it's input ports. Similarly, the other `quirk` is informing that the component will also prefer to allocate on it's output ports. For a list of supported `quirks` in the system, you could refer to the function `OMXCodec::getComponentQuirks` in [OMXCodec.cpp](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#236) file. These quirks translate into flags which are then read by the framework to create and initialize the components.

In the example illustration, it is shown that your `OMX` component is registered prior to the *default* Google implemented video decoder.

**NOTE**: If you trying this on an end device, you will have to ensure that this entry is reflected in the final `media_codecs.xml` file.

**2. OMX Core Registration**

To create your component and ensure that the correct **factory method** is invoked, you *may have* to register your `OMX` Core with the `Stagefright` framework.

To register a new core, you will have to create a new library named `libstagefrighthw.so` which will be located at `/system/lib` in your end system. This library will have to expose a `createOMXPlugin` symbol which will be looked by `dlsym`.

The registration of the `OMX` core is thus: `OMXMaster` invokes `addVendorPlugin` which internally invokes `addPlugin("libstagefrighthw.so")`. In `addPlugin`, the `createOMXPlugin` will be looked up using which the other function pointers for `makeComponentInstance`, `destroyComponentInstance` etc are initialized.

Once the `OMX` core is initialized, you are ready to run your own your component within the android framework. The reference for `OMXMaster` can be found [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/OMXMaster.cpp#46).

With these changes, your video decoder is integrated into the android stagefright framework.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. However i'm a bit confused.

Comment: Say i have a project in which there is a file explorer to select an input file to decode and a decode button to decode the input file. How do i proceed towards the above steps? waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Zax I have answered this on another thread here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356629/how-to-create-a-stagefright-plugin

Comment: @Ganesh, Does the above procedure require you to again built the whole source code with changes made to libstagefrighthw.so ?

Comment: @Steve.. Initially you can build `libstagefrighthw.so` and replace the libraries in `/system/lib`. After replacing the libs, you would require to restart `mediaserver` and voila!... your changes should work fine. From the next overall build, the changes would automatically be part of the build system and `system.img` which wouldn't require any additional steps on your behalf. Hope this helps.