# How to create a stagefright plugin

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-framework, stagefright

I have a task which involves integration of a video decoder into `Stagefright`(Android's multimedia framework). I searched and found the following about creating a new plugin for `Stagefright`:

**To add support for a new format, you need to:**

- Develop a new Extractor class, if the container is not supported yet.
- Develop a new Decoder class, that implements the interface needed by the `StageFright` core to read the data.
- Associate the mime-type of the files to read to your new Decoder in the `OMXCodec.cpp` file, in the `kDecoderInfo` array.

```cs
    static const CodecInfo kDecoderInfo[] = {  
        {MEDIA_MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC, "OMX.TI.AAC.decode"},
        {MEDIA_MIMETYPE_AUDIO_AAC, "AACDecoder"},
    };
```

The above data is all i could find out on net. Right now i have a simple app that will take a file as an input and render it on the screen using native API's in android. Can anyone please tell me how to proceed further. And from where does all these `OMXCodec.cpp` and others come into picture and which directory of my project should i have them in. Please provide solutions regarding the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From your question, it appears that you are looking at a recommendation which is specific for `Ice-Cream Sandwich` or earlier versions of Android. The first thing you should be clear about is the version of the android i.e. `Ice-Cream Sandwich` or before or `JellyBean` and after. The integration of codecs **is different** across different releases of Android.

I have already commented on your other question which is specific for `JellyBean` and later (Reference: [Android: How to integrate a decoder to multimedia framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework))

If you would like to integrate your codec in `Ice-Cream Sandwich` or before, the steps are already available in your question. In addition to adding the decoder into `kDecoderInfo` list, you may like to setup certain quirks as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#322).

For the question on `OMXCodec.cpp`, you can find this file at 
`frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/` in case of `Ice-Cream Sandwich` and `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/` in case of `JellyBean`.

If you have followed all the steps to integrate the video decoder into the `Stagefright` framework, then the easiest test would be to perform the following:

1. Copy a media file into SD-Card
2. In `OMXCodec.cpp`, enable logs by removing the comment in this statement `//#define LOG_NDEBUG 0` and run a `mm` in the directory. Copy the rebuilt `libstagefright.so` to `/system/lib` on your device.
3. Enable `logcat` and start capturing logs.
4. Goto gallery, select your file and allow the standard player to play your file.
5. Check your log file if the player has selected your `OMX` component by searching for your component name. If found, your integration of codec into `Stagefright` is successful. Else, you will have to debug and find out what is the problem.

**Postscript:**

1. Based on your queries, I presume you aren't familiar with Android sources. Please refer to [androidxref](http://androidxref.com/) site to become familiar with `AOSP` distributions.
2. Unless you are planning to support a new media file-format, you will not require to support `Extractor` class. `MediaExtractor` abstracts a file-format parser and helps to de-multiplex the different tracks in a media file.

I hope with this information, you should be able to get your codec integrated and functional in Android.

Comment: Thanks a lot... With this info i'm sure i can proceed. If possible can you please provide a specific link where i can know from the basics about android sources. In the above given link http://androidxref.com/ i'm not able to find the basics for how to start using android sources in my project. I would be really greatful to you if you could provide a source for how to use android sources in any application. Also a small query: are we modifying the android source code here or just creating a standalone plugin for the existing source code.?

Comment: @Zax If you are looking for a Java level introduction, you could start here: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html. However, if you are looking at integration notes, then you could read more in stackoverflow archives. For integrating the codec in `Ice-Cream Sandwich` you will have to modify the Android Sources. For integration into `JellyBean`, you are updating a platform specific file and not the sources, which is the expected mode of integration

Comment: Finally i understood that i need to rebuild a part of the android source code and create a libstagefright.so using an Android.mk and replace it with the existing one in /system/libs in my device. Now inorder to create this *.so file do i need to download the entire android source code or i just need to download frameworks/base/media/libstagefright/ contents?

Comment: @Zax I think you may require more folders under `frameworks/` directory. It would be best if you can sync an entire android forest and keep the same ready.

Comment: You seem well versed in Android media pipeline, Ganesh. I would like to ask you more questions outside Stack Overflow, related to this topic. Are you interested in some consulting work on this topic? Please let me know at saares@axinom.com if so.

Comment: @Ganesh : I was checking your posts on stagefright and really informational. Any possible way in stage fright to access all native video buffers? I was checking for your contact but couldn't find any where.

Comment: @Ayyappa..You can access the `AndroidNativeBuffers` from `CPU` by locking the same. When the buffers are created, you should indicate that you plan read/write from CPU through `GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_WRITE_OFTEN` or `GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_OFTEN` flags as part of the `usage` flags. With this change, you should be able to `lock` and access the buffers through the `vptr` returned from `lock`.