# How to get the codec list on Android 4.0

Tags: android

Android provides a series of APIs such as 'MediaCodec' which can enable the user to get the codec information of the system since 4.1(API level 16).

However, my question is how to get a codec list on 4.0.

BTW, I have checked the source code of 4.1, the API implementation gets the info by parsing the file: system/etc/media_codec.xml. But on 4.0, there is NO such file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaCodec` was added in API 16. Before that the available componentes were hardcoded in the implementation and the vendor-provided omx library. And there was no api in the java side of things to do this sort of thing. From C++ you could poke stagefright and get that info, for example by calling the `stagefright` program (with `-l` or `-p`) in the adb shell. See http://source.android.com/devices/media.html for info on how the lower layers check for available codecs. In previous versions the information that is now in the xml files was in the c/c++ source code. The source for the `stagefright` program (http://androidxref.com/4.0.4/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp ), would be a good place to start and see how the list of components can be obtained. Look at the `if (listComponents)` block in the `main` function.

More Info: [How to create a stagefright plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356629/how-to-create-a-stagefright-plugin) Here there's some background on how the codecs deal-y-o is done in both versions I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most technically exciting solution, but you could simply hardcode the information in the [Core Media Formats table](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#core) in the Android docs.

There could be cases in which a device had some codecs above and beyond what was guaranteed in that version that this method would miss, but that might be acceptable for your purposes.