# How to compile Android jellybean source code

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framework

I am new to android development,
I am developing a play back feature on Google nexus 10 tablet , which plays specific video format , we have video Decoder.

For that i have downloaded android 4.2 jelly bean source code but , I don't know the steps to Build , compile or how to proceed further with android media framework (for play back feature ).

I searched in Google i got few link's from xda developer forum :-

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2...code-on-ubuntu
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37097861 but this link specified for HTC mobile .

The steps are for HTC mobile ,but i am looking for Google Nexus 10 , will the steps remains same or few changes are their for building on google nexus 10.

Kindly educate me on procedure to follow /or any data/ link which specify in detail about the same.

Thanks in advance ... !
Regards ,
S.J

---

actually i got the steps for compile the source code,

but the problem is dont know how and where to place  my custom HW video decoder(Source and Include files),i have referred stack overflow questions answered by ganesh i am thankful to him also he educated me lot these links

[Android: How to integrate a decoder to multimedia framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework)

[How to create a stagefright plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356629/how-to-create-a-stagefright-plugin/15362839#15362839)

but the problem is still, I am not getting the correct method ,
can any one educate me detail , i am very near to deadline so  your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Sayed Junaid

Comment: Why do you need to build the Android OS if you are developing an app?

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Nexus devices the procedure actually gets easier. The complete instructions how to prepare your environment and build AOSP you can find here: http://source.android.com/source/building.html

After downloading the sources you also need to get proprietary devices, which you can find here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers)

The instruction how to build AOSP for Nexus devices you can find here: http://source.android.com/source/building-devices.html