# Custom Wrapper Codec Integration into Android

Tags: android, codec, stagefright

I need to develop a custom 'wrapper' video codec and integrate it into android (JB for now, ICS later).  We want to use some custom decryption keys from the SIM (don't ask!).  The best method (that would allow it to work alongside other non-encrypted media and to use the standard media player or other) seems to be to define our own mime-type, and link that to a custom wrapper codec that can do the custom decryption, and then pass the data on to a real codec. (Let's say the filetype is `.mp4` for now.)

(An alternative might be to write our own media player, but we'd rather not go down that route because we really want the media to appear seamlessly alongside other media)

I've been trying to follow this guide:
[how to integrate a decoder into multimedia framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework)

1. I'm having trouble with OMX Core registration - I can build the `libstagefright.so` from the android source by typing `make stagefright` but in the guide he says to use the `libstagefrighthw.so` which seems appropriate for JB, but I'm not sure how to build this, it doesn't seem to get built from using `make stagefright` unless I'm doing something wrong?
2. The other problem is that even if I do get the custom wrapper codec registered, I'm not sure how to go about passing the data off to a real codec.

If anyone has any suggestions (or can give some baby step by step instructions!), I'd really appreciate it - the deadline is quite tight for the proof of concept and I know very little about codecs or the media framework...

Many Thanks.
(p.s. I don't want to get into a mud fight about drm and analogue holes etc.., thanks)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this post, I am using `H.264` as an example, but the solution(s) can be extended to support other codecs like `MPEG-4`, `VC-1`, `VP8` etc. There are 2 possible solutions to solve your problem, which I am enlisting below, each with their own pros and cons to help you take an informed decision.

**Solution 1: Extend the codec to support new mode**

In `JellyBean`, one could register the same `OMX` component with same `MIME` types as 2 different component names viz., `OMX.ABC.XYZ` and `OMX.ABC.XYZ.secure`. The former is used for normal playback and is the more commonly used component. The latter is used when the parser i.e. `MediaExtractor` indicates the presence of **secure content**. In `OMXCodec::Create`, after `findMatchingCodecs` returns a list of codecs, we can observe the choice to select `.secure` component as [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#319).

*Steps to follow:*

1. In your platform, register another component with some new extension like `OMX.H264.DECODER.decrypt` or something similar. Change is required only in `media_codecs.xml`. The choice of whether to register a new factory method or have a common factory method is your choice.
2. From your parser, when you encounter the specific use-case, set a new flag like `kKeyDecryptionRequired`. For this you will have to define a new flag in [`Metadata.h`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/MetaData.h#132) and a corresponding quirk in [`OMXCodec.h`](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/OMXCodec.h#89).
3. Modify the `OMXCodec::create` method to append a `.decrypt` suffix similar to the `.secure` suffix as shown above.
4. With all changes in `OMXCodec`, `Metadata`, `MediaExtractor` modules, you will have to rebuild only `libstagefright.so` and replace the same on your platform.

Voila!! your integration should be complete. Now comes the main challenge inside the component. As part of the component implementation, you should be able to differentiate between an ordinary component creation and `.decrypt` component creation.

From a runtime perspective, assuming that your component is aware of the fact that it is a `.decrypt` component or not, you could handle the `decryption` as part of the `OMX_EmptyThisBuffer` call, where you could decrypt the data and then pass it to underlying codec.

**Pros:** Easy to integrate, Minimal changes in Android framework, Scalable to other codecs, No new `MIME` type registration required.

**Cons:** You need to track the future revisions of android, specifically on the new quirks, flags and choice of `.decrypt` extension. If Google decides to employ something similar, you will have to adapt / modify your solution accordingly.

**Solution 2: Registration of new MIME Type**

From your question, it is not clear if you were able to define the `MIME` type or not and hence, I am capturing the steps for clarity.

**Steps to follow:**

1. Register a new `MIME` type at `MediaDefs` as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaDefs.cpp#24). For example, you could employ a new `MIME` type as `const char *MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC_ENCRYPT = "video/avc-encrypt";`
2. Register your new component with this updated `MIME` type in `media_codecs.xml`. Please note that you will have to ensure that the component quirks are also handled accordingly.
3. In `OMXCodec::setVideoOutputFormat` method implementation, you will have to introduce the support for handling your new `MIME` type as shown for `H.264` [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp#1181). Please note that you will have to handle similar changes in `OMXCodec` to support the new `MIME` type.
4. In `MediaExtractor`, you will have to signal the `MIME` type for the `video` track  using the newly defined type. With these changes, your component will be selected and created.

**However,** the challenge still remains: Where to perform the decryption? For this, you could as well employ the same solution as described in the previous section i.e. handle the same as part of `OMX_EmptyThisBuffer` call.

**Pros:** None that I can think of..

**Cons:** First, solution is not scalable. You will have to keep adding newer `MIME` types and keep modifying the `Stagefright` framework. Next, the changes in `OMXCodec` will require corresponding changes in `MediaExtractor`. Hence, even though your initial focus is on `MP4` extractor, if you wish to extend the solution to other container formats like `AVI`, `MKV`, you will have to include the support for new `MIME` types in these extractors.

**Lastly,** some notes.

1. As a preferred solution, I would recommend Solution 1 as it is easy and simple.
2. I haven't touched upon `ACodec` based implementation of the codec. However, I do feel that Solution 1 would be a far more easier solution to implement even if such a support is required in future.
3. If you aren't modifying the `OMX` core, you shouldn't require to modify the `libstagefrighthw.so`. Just FYI, this is typically implemented by the vendors as part of their vendor specific modules as in `vendor/<xyz>/hardware/...`. You need to check with your platform provider on the sources for `libstagefrighthw.so`.

Comment: Thanks so much Ganesh, this is awesome.  We've had to implement a custom media player for now because of time constraints, but will be returning to your Solution 1 very soon...  Thanks again.

Comment: @Matthew I am working on exactly same requirement with tight timelines. Have to decrypt files before decoding. Which player you chose for this one?? Please suggest me one. Thanks

Comment: @Sree In the end I've abandoned modifying Android for now. I based a custom player on this example: [Cedric Fung](https://github.com/vecio/MediaCodecDemo).  After the line `int sampleSize = extractor.readSampleData(buffer, 0);` you can decrypt the buffer. (I've built a simple encryptor to encrypt the sample data and make an enc movie file - just need to parse the boxes and reencode the lengths after encrypting the data). Hope that helps!