# Integrating a Codec to Android multimedia framework

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-framework, stagefright

I have a custom codec, which is currently not supported by the android multimedia framework. Using the codec's source code i have created a simple video player app for the new format. However now i would like to integrate it to androids multimedia frame work.

With the help of the post:

[How to integrate a decoder to multimedia framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework)

I got to know the basics that i need. First of all i need to integrate my codec into Jelly Bean and above versions. Hence following the above post, i have downloaded the android source code and as specified in the above post, i have added my Decoder information in `media_codecs.xml` a code snippet of it is shown below:

```
<Decoders>
    <MediaCodec name="OMX.CustomDecoder.DECODER" type="video/avc" >
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-input-ports" />
        <Quirk name="requires-allocate-on-output-ports" />
    </MediaCodec>
.
.
.
```

Once i have done the above,

- what i'm thinking is, in which directory of the android source tree should i
  add the source code of my **customDecoder**.
- Once i have added my **customDecoder** code, in which place should i give
  commands/ write make file to compile my source code.
- And atlast when everything has been successfully build and compiled,
  if i want to test my integration in android emulator, what should be
  the steps to be performed.

Any experts who know something about my queries, please please answer them.

Thanks in advance.

-Regards

sam

Comment: Someone please Provide me with some solution.

Comment: I have a similar issue with my custom decoder, since this post was made in August 2013, were you able to find any solution for your query. If yes, could you please share with me any headstarts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can some expert provide solution for this question? it will be helpful to many including me.

Comment: if anyone got answer ...please post