# How to register a OMX core for adding a new decoder

Tags: android, android-framework, stagefright, openmax

I'm referring to the post:

[Android: How to integrate a decoder to multimedia framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework)

Following it i have registered my new decoder (Which is currently not supported by Android) in `media_codecs.xml`.

The Step 2 of the above post requires me to perform **OMX core registration**. However, Since i'm really new to this topic, i'm not able to follow the step 2.

I have the working code of the decoder in C and is already ported to android.

So i request if anybody can provide information on:

- A step-by-step guide to preform OMX code registration for a decoder
  that is currently not supported by android.
- Where should i place my working C code in the source tree and how to 
  specify the compiler to compile it
- Lastly, i would like to tell that i'm working on ICS code and the
  output of the decoders source code is YUV420.

Anyone please provide pointers towards the above queries. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the structure of [the already available codecs](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libstagefright/codecs?h=jb_mr1) and how MIME types are mapped to the appropriate codec by the [OMXCodec class](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/frameworks/av/tree/media/libstagefright/OMXCodec.cpp?h=jb_mr1).

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for your reply. So according to you changes are needed to be performed only in OMXCodec class is it? I'm not sure, as i have already said i hardly have any experience in this. If you know some details please do provide it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know if those are the _only_ changes necessary. But I figured it could serve as a starting point at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your don't plan to have your own `OMX Core`, then you can consider adding your codec to the `SoftOMXComponent` plugin itself as described below.

**Note:** This answer assumes that you have the **ability to recompile a portion** of `AOSP` code and can **replace the rebuilt libraries** on your platform.

**Step 1: Registration of `OMX` Component**

In `SoftOMXComponent` source file as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/SoftOMXPlugin.cpp#36), add your component name as shown below

```
{ "OMX.sam.custom.h264.decoder", "sam_h264dec", "video_decoder.avc" }
```

Here `"OMX.sam.custom.h264.decoder"` represents your component name, `"sam_h264dec"` represents the suffix of the name of the library stored in the file system (more below) and `"video_decoder.avc"` represents the role of your decoder, which  in this example is a `H.264` video decoder.

**Step 2: Generation of library**

Your `OMX` component should be built as a dynamically loadable library whose name would be `"libstagefright_soft_sam_h264dec.so"` and should be placed at **/system/lib** of your file system.

**Step 3: Creation of the component**

The `Stagefright` framework code will look for a symbol named `createSoftOMXComponent` to create the component. Hence, your codec library mentioned in Step 2 should support this function.

With these steps and **assuming** your codec is `OMX` compatible with `Android` extensions, you should be able to integrate your decoder.

**Tip 1:** If you wish that your component is always selected, please ensure that your component name as described in Step 1 is registered at the very top of `kComponents` array in the shown reference.

**Tip 2:** If you wish to know more on the topic of generation of the dynamically loadable library, you could refer to the `GSM Decoder` code as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/codecs/gsm/dec/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From the example that you have referred, that is the GSM Decoder, i assume that my code should be placed in /Codecs/myDec directory in the source tree. Is this assumption true? Second doubt is, how do i make my codec library support createSoftOMXComponent symbol? Any simple example or reference for this will be a saviour to me. Please Help..

Comment: @Ganesh In step-2 What are source file require to create libstagefright_soft_sam_h264dec.so ? What - I understand is h.264 decoder source code and OMX component  integration source file and header file ? Is it required any thing from AOSP?

Comment: @Mohan.. The `libstagefright_soft_sam_h264dec.so` was a __customized version__ of the decoder written by the originator of the question. Unless you are developing a custom `software` based `decoder`, this step is not necessary. I hope this clarifies

Comment: @Ganesh I had up vote to your ans but i am not getting your **Note** part ,what AOSP portion need to recompile and which rebuild lib to replace on target?

Comment: @Mohan.. The note is for registering a `SoftOMXComponent` i.e. only if you are registering your own __software__ based codec. If you are employing the traditional `OMX` core registration, then this step is not required. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @Ganesh Thanks...i am new in android .i have software based hevc decoder and i am thinking to do `SoftOMXComponent` Registration. so i understand what to change in source file but How to build it ? What to replace at targe?

Comment: @Mohan.. I am sharing an example with `Lollipop` version of code which should work for others too. Once you register the `SoftOMXComponent`, you need to replace the `libstagefright_omx.so`. Please check this link: http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/omx/Android.mk. I would recommend you to replace all libraries under `frameworks/av/media/libstagefright` which would be `libstagefright.so`, the `omx` lib, other `softomx` components.