# android MediaSource not recogonized as class in jni code

Tags: android, stagefright

I am trying to use  `android` `ndk` to develop simple `decoder`/`player` application.I created one project using `android` `sdk` and then i created a folder named jni in my project directory.
Inside the jni directory i created one `omx.cpp` file and i want to write my own class inside this which inherits Android `MediaSource` from `stagefright`.I have also included `stagefright` header files in my project.I am loading `libstagefright.so` by using **`dlopen`** in my `omx.cpp` file.

the code i am using is as follows:

```
using android::sp;

namespace android
{

class ImageSource : public MediaSource {
public:
ImageSource(int width, int height, int colorFormat)
: mWidth(width),
  mHeight(height),
  mColorFormat(colorFormat)
 {

  }

public:
int mWidth;
int mHeight;
int mColorFormat;

 virtual status_t start(MetaData *params = NULL) {}

 virtual status_t stop() {}

 // Returns the format of the data output by this media source.
 virtual sp<MetaData> getFormat() {}

 virtual status_t read(
    MediaBuffer **buffer, const MediaSource::ReadOptions *options) {
 }

/*protected:
virtual ~ImageSource() {}*/
};



void Java_com_exampleomxvideodecoder_MainActivity(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject    surface)
{

    void *dlhandle;

    dlhandle = dlopen("d:\libstagefright.so", RTLD_NOW);
    if (dlhandle == NULL)  {
        printf("Service  Not Found:  %s\n", dlerror());
    }
    int width = 720;
    int height = 480;
    int colorFormat = 0;

    sp<MediaSource> img_source = new ImageSource(width, height, colorFormat);

    sp<MetaData> enc_meta = new MetaData;
   // enc_meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_H263);
   // enc_meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4);
   enc_meta->setCString(kKeyMIMEType, MEDIA_MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyWidth, width);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyHeight, height);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeySampleRate, kFramerate);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyBitRate, kVideoBitRate);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyStride, width);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeySliceHeight, height);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyIFramesInterval, kIFramesIntervalSec);
   enc_meta->setInt32(kKeyColorFormat, colorFormat);


   sp<MediaSource> encoder =
       OMXCodec::Create(
               client.interface(), enc_meta, true, image_source);

   sp<MPEG4Writer> writer = new MPEG4Writer("/sdcard/screenshot.mp4");
   writer->addSource(encoder);

   // you can add an audio source here if you want to encode audio as well

   sp<MediaSource> audioEncoder =
   OMXCodec::Create(client.interface(), encMetaAudio, true, audioSource);
   writer->addSource(audioEncoder);

   writer->setMaxFileDuration(kDurationUs);
   CHECK_EQ(OK, writer->start());
   while (!writer->reachedEOS()) {
       fprintf(stderr, ".");
       usleep(100000);
   }
   err = writer->stop();
}
}
```

I  have following doubts:

1.In `jni` function is it okay if we create some class objects and use them to call functions of say `MediaSource` class or we have to create separate .cpp and .h files.If we use separate files how do we call/ref it from jni function.

2.Is this the right approach to make our own wrapper class which inherits from `MediaSource` class or is there any other way.

Basically i want to make an application which takes `.mp4`/`.avi` file,`demux` it separate audio/video,decode and render/play it using android `stagefright` and `OpenMAX` only.

If `ffmpeg` is suggested for source,`demux`ing then how to integrate it with `android` `st
agefright` framework.

Regards

Comment: Please share some logs and your `Android.mk` or `makefile` and some sources that shows how you are employing `MediaSource` in your code. Based on these information, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your **first** question, **Yes** it is possible to define a `class` in the same source file and instantiate the same in a function below. A best example which I feel could be very good example for such an implementation would be the `DummySource` of the `recordVideo` utility which can be found in [`cmds`](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/recordvideo.cpp) directory.

However, your file should include the [`MediaSource.h`](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/av/include/media/stagefright/MediaSource.h) file either directly or indirectly as can be found in the aforementioned example too.

The **second** question is more of an implementation choice or religion. For some developers, defining a new class and inheriting from `MediaSource` might be the right way as you have tried in your example.

There is an alternate implementation where you can create the source and typecast into a `MediaSoure` strong pointer as shown in the example below.

```
<sp><MediaSource>   mVideoSource;
mVideoSource = new ImageSource(width, height, colorformat);
```

where `ImageSource` implements `start` and `read` methods. I feel `recordVideo` example above is a good reference.

Regarding the last paragraph, I will respond on your other query, but I feel there is a fundamental mismatch between your objective and code. The objective is to create a `parser` or `MediaExtractor` and a corresponding `decoder`, but the code above is instantiating an `ImageSource` which I presume gives `YUV` frames and creating an `encoder` as you are passing `true` for encoder creation.

I will also add further comments on the `NDK` possibilities on the other thread.

Comment: how to integrate omx codec component as hardware component in android code.Also is it possible to be able to query at application level whether framework is using omx software or  hardware component as decoder.

Comment: @MayankAgarwal.. To add any `OMX` component, please check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework/15343639#15343639 . When you refer to an application, can you please be more specific which application you are looking at? For ex: In case of example command line utilities like `stagefright`, there is a methodology to prefer the software codec as here:http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp#600 . Can you please post a different ques, if this doesn't answer your current query?

Comment: Currently i have android open source code for a multimedia product and  the project uses its customised mediaplayer far better than stagefright,that player selection is done in MediaPlayerService.cpp(android is also doing same thing).But instead of STAGEFRIGHT_PLAYER it is creating its own player.If i remove that customisation then m3u8 file(android uses NU Player for playing m3u8 file) is not playing because of crash happening in OMX software decoder.Now how can i change this omx software decoder to some other decoder which can play m3u8 file.

Comment: @MayankAgarwal.. In your `media_codecs.xml` file, ensure that your preferred decoder is the first one to be present in the file for a given `mime` type. This way, there will not be fallback to the software decoder. Usually, the flow falls back to SW decoder only if it couldn't find any other codec type. Which codec are you having an issue with??

Comment: Is there any way i can select the decoder component at application level and give it to omxcodec.cpp through jni

Comment: @MayankAgarwal.. Are you using `MediaCodec` or `MediaPlayer`? If you are using `MediaPlayer`, you can't configure the component i.e. `OMXCodec` below. By standard `AOSP` methodology, if your codec is the first one in the list of codecs, it should get selected. If you want to really customize, then you can try one experiment. In your codec's entry in `media_codecs.xml`, add a new custom mime-type as another role and while creating `MediaCodec`, provide this mime type. This will help to ensure that your preferred codec is only always created.