# Android: Creating an OMX component for a video decoder

Tags: android, ffmpeg, stagefright, video-codecs, openmax

I have a new task of integrating a decoder(`HEVC`) from `FFMPEG` to Android's `Stagefright`. To do this, i first need to created an `OMX` component, My next thing is to register my codec in `media_codecs.xml` and then the `OMX` component registration in `OMXCore`.

Is there any guide or steps to create an `OMX` component for a video decoder? Secondly, this decoder plays only elementary streams (`.bin` or `.h265` files) so there is no container format here.

Can anyone provide some steps or guidelines to be followed while creating the `OMX` component for a video codec. Any sort of pointers will be really helpful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you could follow the [steps pointed in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework) for integrating a decoder into `OMX` Core.

`HEVC` is not yet part of the `OMX` `IL` specification. Hence, you would have to introduce a new `role` like `video_decoder.hevc` for your component while registering in `media_codecs.xml`. Please do check that your `OMX` core can support this new `role`.

If you are trying to play only elementary streams, you can consider modifying the [`stagefright` command line utility](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/stagefright.cpp#163) to read the elementary stream data and feed the decoder.

Another option is to modify the current [`recordVideo` utility](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/recordvideo.cpp#299) to read a frame data and create a `decoder` instead of the `encoder`. With these, I presume you should be able to play your decoder from command line.

**EDIT:** If you wish to build a new `OMX` component, I would recommend that you could refer to the [*Bellagio Component Writers Guide*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/omxil/files/documentation/OMX%20component%20writers_%20guide/) which should give good information on how to build an OMX component. This gives a pretty comprehensive guide to build a new component. Please do ensure that you are able to identify the dependencies with the Bellagio implementation and your core implementation.

Also, you could look at other public domain `OMX` implementations as here: 
http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/hardware/ti/omap4xxx/domx/ 
http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/hardware/qcom/media/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/

I feel Bellagio could work as a good starting reference if you haven't build an `OMX` component earlier. The sources for Bellagio are available on [Sourceforge](http://omxil.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have two queries, One is the steps given in above link is for registration of an omx component or developing an omx component? Second, I think i can use the stagefright command line utility, but integration in that way, will it play a video from the gallery?

Comment: @Zax.. The steps described is for the registration and integration of the `OMX` component. I presume you already have an `OMX` component and hence, I am not answering the same. If you want to play your video straight out of gallery, then a lot of changes would be required as your input is just an elementary stream. You will have to create a `MediaExtractor` specifically for this file which will have to be integrated and registered.. there is a lot of stuff to be done if you want to make the file playable from gallery..

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The media extractor i think i can use the hevc_parser in ffmpeg. No, i dont have an OMX component. Actually that is only the question all about "Creating an OMX component for a video decoder" Especially the one which is not yet supported. Please provide some pointers regarding this.

Comment: @Zax.. are you familiar with the `OMX` IL specification? The question has a wide range for which I would like to fine tune my answer. If required, we can even chat on `SO` to discuss.

Comment: OMX IL specification is a huge thing. I'm aware of only the overview of it. http://old.siggraph.org/publications/2006cn/course16/OpenMAX.pdf and somw more docs i have read

Comment: @Zax.. Please check the updated answer. I think this should help to answer your query now??

Comment: thanks for the material. I'll get back to u in case i have any queries after reading the component developers guide