# How to enable hardware decoder in rowboat JellyBean 4.1.1

Tags: android, media-player, codec

I m trying to enable Hardware codec in rowboat JB 4.1.1

I have followed the below procedure.

Referring  :  **https://source.android.com/devices/media.html**

**Steps:**

1) Downloaded rowboat JB 4.1.1 from TI.

2)  I do not see OMAX IL implementation for omap3 in rowboat, Hence downloaded from AOSP.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/ti/omap3  -b jb-release
```

3)  I built the Framework, and figured the below files in system/lib  libstagefrighthw.so, libhardware.so libbridge.so

4) I have modified  /etc/media_codec.xml  by adding the below lines. [ Removed default software encoders ]

```
    <MediaCodec name="OMX.TI.Video.Decoder" type="video/avc"/>

</Decoders>

<Encoders>

    <MediaCodec name="OMX.TI.Video.encoder" type="video/avc"/>

</Encoders>
```

5) Flashed image into SD Card, and rebooted the device,

6) When i am running with default media player from gallery, it shouts at me saying "can not play this video".

I am sure, i have missed a lot. Also, i do not find what is the underpinning details to accomplish  enabling hardware encoding.

Expecting your kind help!!!

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any logs from your experiment? Also, please do have a look at this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334509/android-how-to-integrate-a-decoder-to-multimedia-framework/15343639#15343639 . Can you confirm if your codec is indeed registered with the `OMX` core in the system? If you have any further logs, we can help..

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have create another thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22956265/emabling-hardware-encoder-in-jelly-bean-4-1-1-rowboat-dm3730   with detailed error. Your help would be much appreciated.